# почему мне выдаёт ошибку TabError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pep8

Хотел сделать симулятор открытия бокса на *Python* используя *tkinter*.

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint
from time import sleep

chance = randint(0,100)

def open():
    if chance > 90 and chance < 101:
        resp = ('leon')
    elif chance > 45 and chance < 91:
        resp = ('nita')
    elif chance > 0 and chance < 46:
        resp = ('shelly')
    res.set(resp)

win = tk.Tk()
win.resizable(False,False)
win.geometry('100x100')
win.title('Box Leon Farm')
win['bg'] = 'yellow'

res = tk.StringVar()

mainlb = tk.Label(text = 'Leon Farm',bg = 'yellow')
lb = tk.Label(textvariable=res)
btn =tk.Button(text = 'Open', height = 3,width = 6,command=open)
mainlb.pack()
lb.pack()
btn.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Все так, но выдаёт ошибку:

> TabError, проверить наличие пространства и табов.

Comment: Это ваш вольный перевод ошибки? ;) Видимо вы использовали символы табуляции и пробелы вперемешку. Проверьте, что у вас везде отступы сделаны при помощи пробелов и они все одинаковы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Правила оформления Python-кода:

- **`Отступы`**.
  Рекомендуется использовать **`4 пробела`** на каждый уровень отступа.
  Python 3 запрещает смешивание табуляции и пробелов в отступах. 
  Код, в котором используются и те, и другие типы отступов,
  должен быть исправлен так, чтобы отступы в нем были расставлены
  только с помощью пробелов.

2. Вы генерируете случайное целое число N,  0 ≤ N ≤ 100,
   а в функции `open()`, значение **`0`** (ноля) не обрабатываете.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint
#from time import sleep

#chance = randint(0, 100)

def open():
    chance = randint(0, 100)                             # +++

    if chance > 90 and chance < 101:
        resp = ('leon')
    elif chance > 45 and chance < 91:
        resp = ('nita')
#    elif chance > 0 and chance < 46:
    elif chance >= 0 and chance < 46:                    # +++
        resp = ('shelly')
    res.set(resp)

win = tk.Tk()
win.resizable(False, False)
win.geometry('150x150')
win.title('Box Leon Farm')
win['bg'] = 'yellow'

res = tk.StringVar()

mainlb = tk.Label(text='Leon Farm', bg='yellow')
lb = tk.Label(textvariable=res)
btn =tk.Button(text='Open', height=3, width=6, command=open)
mainlb.pack()
lb.pack()
btn.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, значит ошибка в том что генерацию числа надо было поставить в функцию?

Comment: @user466898 нет. у вас были нарушения правил оформления Python-кода. Я перенес генерацию числа в функцию - просто посчитав, что ей там место. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour